# How should one handle different types of users in a MERN application?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mern

For instance, I am currently developing a side-project to learn the MERN stack.

How should one handle having different types of users(in the sense that they have different fields). For instance, a user might be a Customer(so he might have stuff like a list of orders, a cart etc) but another user might be a Vendor(a list of products being sold by the vendor,  general information about him etc).

In a language such as Java this would be probably done by having a POJO User class and then having two different entities (Vendor and Customer) making use of inheritance mechanism and thus extending the User class who has the basic properties(username, password, e-mail etc).

What would be the optimally way to handle this using MongoDB with Mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

You can have role in mongoose user schema and then on the basis of user role you can show different ui in frontend and also in backend you can authorize apis on the basis of user role.
You can try something like this.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please enter your email"],
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please enter your passwword"],
    minlength: [6, "password should be minimum six charactors"],
    select: false,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Vendor", "Customer"],
    default: "Customer",
  },
///some other fields////
  });
   
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```